# Google Play Billing Library 5.0 deprecation warnings

Tags: java, android, deprecation-warning, play-billing-library

Since I've upgraded the `BillingClient` to version `5.0.0`:

```
googleImplementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:5.0.0'
```

I get these unique deprecation warnings:

```
warning: [deprecation] getSkus() in Purchase has been deprecated
warning: [deprecation] getSkus() in PurchaseHistoryRecord has been deprecated
warning: [deprecation] SkuType in BillingClient has been deprecated
warning: [deprecation] SkuDetailsResponseListener in com.android.billingclient.api has been deprecated
warning: [deprecation] SkuDetailsParams in com.android.billingclient.api has been deprecated
warning: [deprecation] SkuDetails in com.android.billingclient.api has been deprecated
warning: [deprecation] querySkuDetailsAsync(SkuDetailsParams,SkuDetailsResponseListener) in BillingClient has been deprecated
warning: [deprecation] setSkuDetails(SkuDetails) in Builder has been deprecated
```

eg. the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetailsResponseListener) suggests to use [`ProductDetailsResponseListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#queryProductDetailsAsync(com.android.billingclient.api.QueryProductDetailsParams,%20com.android.billingclient.api.ProductDetailsResponseListener)) instead.

Wanted to ask, how to use it?

Comment: Have you checked the migration guide? https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate-gpblv5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SkuDetailsResponseListener` is replaced by `ProductDetailsResponseListener` along with other methods & callbacks since **v5** adds new subscription capabilities (as per docs.).

You can check the complete migration guide here:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate-gpblv5